# Load json-data into Highchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I've struggled for some hours with the problem of putting a highchart in a dynamically created popup. Until now I've finished this part, but now I have the problem that I'm not able to load my used data to my highchart.

I've prepared two examples.
**(1):** Firstly one example, which work without any problems. Local data are used, highchart is created in a dynamically created div:
http://jsfiddle.net/AL3nT/2/
**(2):** Secondly a example with my actual problem. I have to say that I'm new to jquery and I'm not a talented programmer (I'm even happy that I am at this level :D) and it took me some time to change the code to work with dynamical-created stuff...
http://jsfiddle.net/AL3nT/3/
As you may notice there is not data.
The data itself should be loaded by the following:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.pegelonline.wsv.de/webservices/rest-api/v2/stations/BONN/W/measurements.json?start=P1D', function (data) {
                chart_data = [];
                $.each(data, function (i, obj) {
                    chart_data.push([Date.parse(obj.timestamp), obj.value]);
                });
                options.series[0].data = chart_data;
                var chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
            });
        });
```

My problem is that I don't know how to combine the fiddle from **(2)** and the data-gathering part. Of course I know that I don't have the options part anymore, but I don't know hot to pass it through my chart (previously it looked like this one http://jsfiddle.net/x6d3j/1/, where I had the options parameter.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Is there a way we can see the data returned by the `$.getJSON()` call?

Comment: Of course - I've added and edited the link to my question, so the `$.getJSON()` call will have a  request.

Comment: Is that the actual data you want to use for the chart?

Comment: @user3558931 Jepp. Although I have a working example here http://jsfiddle.net/x6d3j/1/, but this is without the jqeury stuff, which I want to use.

Comment: Look at the demo in the answer below and confirm if that's what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is [**this**](http://jsfiddle.net/AL3nT/5/) what you're looking for? I changed:

```
$('#container').hightcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'spline',
        shadow: true
    }//,
    //........
});
```

To:

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        type: 'spline',
        shadow: true
    }//,
    //....
};
```

And put the ajax call at the bottom of DOM ready, no changes made to it.

Comment: Thanks so much :) This was exactly that I was looking for. I definitely have to had a deeper look into jqeury ...